# On the references of Eichler-Shimura isomorphism

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Good days, everyone. I am now trying to understand the so-called Eichler-Shimura isomorphism. For the references, I am now reading the book "Introduction to the Arithmetic Theory of Automorphic Functions" and the paper "Sur les integrales attachees aux formes automorphes" by G. Shimura.

However, these references seem to be a little old. So I am wondering if there is any reference on Eichler-Shimura isomorphism in a more modern way?

Comment: Try these notes by Wiese: http://math.uni.lu/~wiese/notes/MFII.pdf. (You want sections 6.2-6.4).